# How to instantiate BeanFactory in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring

Currently I am trying to use Spring 4 in my application. And I am trying to run programs using main method.

In earlier Spring versions I used to provide the implementations as below

```
BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml"));
```

Now XmlBeanFactory is deprecated in Spring 4. So how can I do the same thing in Spring 4.

Comment: You can do the exact same thing in Spring 4.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. XmlBeanFactory is deprecated in Spring 4

Comment: Does the deprecated type not suggest what alternative to use?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes you are right. It's suggested in Java Doc and thanks for sharing knowledge.

Comment: @MallikarjunS why don't you use `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: @user3218114: I have a need of using BeanFactory itself.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got the solution in other link..